# Linking a Resume Submission HTML form to submit to a MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, apache

I'm new to stack overflow and am trying to set up a resume form on my company's   website that potential employees can use to send us their resume and information. I have experience in basic HTML design, but almost none in MySQL and PHP which I've learned apparently must be used to pull data from form boxes and store it in the DB.

I have a form made already, and I've been trying to get my PHP code to do its job for weeks now and have scoured the web for solutions to no avail.

Here is my HTML form: (note that because it forces line breaks, I had to manually space some of the form-notably on the 1-4 list)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Resume Storage.</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

<form name="ResumeDatabase" action="ResumeDB.php" method="POST">

    <img src="Logo.png" alt="img" width="250" height= "150" /> <br><br>

     <p style="color:#6699FF;" style="font-family: sans-serif"><font
     size="6"><b>Hello, welcome to Blank, Inc.</font></b> </p>

     <p  style="color:black;" style="font-family: sans-serif" ><font      
     size="3"><b>Please
     enter your information in the form below and the attach your resume.       
     </font></b> </p>


     1) First Name:  <input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="15" 
        size="15" style="background-color: white ;color:black"> <br/><br/>
     2) Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="15" 
        size="15" style="background-color: white ;color:black"> <br/><br/>
     3) Email Address:  <input type="text" name="emailAddress" 
        maxlength="40" size="45" style="background-color: white 
        ;color:black"> <br/><br/>  
     4) Years of Experience Acquired:  <input type="text" 
        name="yearsExperience" maxlength="2" size="5" style="background- 
        color: white ;color:black"><br/>

     <p style="color:red;" >*Please only submit Resumes of the PDF file 
      type* </br> </p>

     <input type="file" name="Resume"> 

     <br/><br/>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit Resume Form" onClick="aa();">

</form>
```

For ease of discussion regarding the HTML form above, 
-form name... is line 10 
-1) First Name is line 21
-input type submit is line 32

Now I will post my PHP code, trust me I've checked file names to make sure the codes had the same file names in the realm of committing the 'action'.

I didn't bother with fixing spacing on this one, but keep in mind this is probably a mix of codes or fixes to parse errors from at least 10 different sources.  If I need to just use a totally different code in general I would not be surprised.  FYI the NT and 1 are the username and password.

```
<?php
if( $_POST )
{
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","NT","1");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);  

}
$fName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lName = $_POST['lastName'];
$emailAdd = $_POST['emailAddress'];
$yExperience = $_POST['yearsExperience'];  

$fName = mysql_real_escape_string($fName);
$lName = mysql_real_escape_string($lName); 
$emailAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($emailAdd); 
$yExperience = mysql_real_escape_string($yExperience);

$query = "
INSERT INTO 'NT'.'resume-storage' ('firstName', 'lastName', 'emailAddress', 'yearsExperience')
        VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lName', '$emailAdd', '$yExperience');";

mysql_query($query);

    echo "<h2>Thank you, your information has been stored in our Database.</h2>";

msql_close($con);

?>
```

For ease of discussion regarding the PHP code above, 
-mysql_select_db is line 10 
-$lname=POST is line 15 
-$lname=mysql_real_escape is line 20 
-INSERT INTO is line 25 
-echo is line 30

Here are some code snippets I've tested in and out of the code, but I could have used them in the wrong places: (again I didn't manually edit the spacing)

```
//mysql_connect("localhost", "NT", "1") or die(mysql_error());
//mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
//mysql_query("insert into 'test'.'resume-storage' ('firstName', 'lastName','emailAddress', 'yearsExperience')");

#$connect = mysql_connect(“localhost”, "testadmin", ); if (!connect) { die('Connection Failed: ' . mysql_error()); { mysql_select_db(“test”, $connect);
//$sql = "INSERT INTO resume-storage (firstName, lastName, emailAddress, yearsExperience)
//VALUES ('$first_Name', '$last_Name', '$email_Address', '$yearsExperience')";

//mysql_query(“INSERT INTO resume-storage) VALUES($FirstName, $LastName, $EmailAddress, $YearsExperience)";
//if (!mysql_query($user_info, $connect)) 
    //{ 
//echo “Your information was added to the database.”;

    //die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    //}



//mysql_close($connect);
#('$first_Name', '$last_Name', '$email_Address', '$years_Experience')
/>
```

And here are the most recent errors I've received, it seems as if the text that is being entered in the form isn't being fetched properly.

```
Notice: Undefined index: firstName in C:\xampp\htdocs\ResumeDB.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: lastName in C:\xampp\htdocs\ResumeDB.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: emailAddress in C:\xampp\htdocs\ResumeDB.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: yearsExperience in C:\xampp\htdocs\ResumeDB.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: fname in C:\xampp\htdocs\ResumeDB.php on line 26
Thank you, your information has been stored in our Database.


Fatal error: Call to undefined function msql_close() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ResumeDB.php on line 32
```

Any help is welcome, I have speculated that not having any action for the resume submission button could be killing the submission-but that is a guess.

Thanks, 
Nate

Comment: The errors are pretty self explanatory. Your `INSERT` statement is wrong, remove quotes around table and column names. `$fName` and `$fname` are two different variable. And finally, `msql_close($con);` should be `mysql_close($con);`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul - you mean `mysql_`

Comment: @OliverQueen Yes, that was a typo. :-)

Comment: Unrelated as others are advising adequately, but seriously look into using the mysqli_ functions or - preferably - PDO working with the DB :)

Comment: I made the changes that all of you suggested, and I got a nice return of the "thank you,...." message without any errors.  However, It would appear that the information wasn't actually submitted to the database.  Could it be that everything connected to the MySQL DB but it wasn't retrieving the content from the blanks?

Answer (score 0):

Note : In PHP7 **mysql_**  are removed so take care of it.Please use **mysqli_ or PDO**.

Your Edited code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) &&  isset($_POST['lastName']) && isset($_POST['emailAddress']) && isset($_POST['yearsExperience'])){
if( $_POST )
{
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","NT","1");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);  

}


$fName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lName = $_POST['lastName'];
$emailAdd = $_POST['emailAddress'];
$yExperience = $_POST['yearsExperience'];  

$fName = mysql_real_escape_string($fName);
$lName = mysql_real_escape_string($lName); 
$emailAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($emailAdd); 
$yExperience = mysql_real_escape_string($yExperience);
//Updated insert query
$query = "
INSERT INTO resume-storage (firstName, lastName, emailAddress, yearsExperience)
        VALUES ('$fName', '$lName', '$emailAdd', '$yExperience');";

mysql_query($query);

    echo "<h2>Thank you, your information has been stored in our Database.</h2>";

mysql_close($con); //mysql not msql
}
else
{
  header("Location:localhost:8080/index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please read my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344903/linking-a-resume-submission-html-form-to-submit-to-a-mysql-database#comment58397164_35344903). `$fName` and `$fname` are two different variable. Remove single quotes around table and column names. And remove that `NULL, ` also from the INSERT query.

Comment: How *override* came into picture? Please explain.

Comment: `NULL, ` is still there. I believe I should leave rest of the things to OP to solve.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be carefull the "mysql" library is deprecated and has been removed from PHP7.

Then those `Notice: Undefined index:` says that the `$_POST` might be empty (or that the form inputs are empty too)
To avoid them, do something like this

```
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"]){
    // your code here
//
```

Can you try this ?

```
<?php
if( $_POST )
{
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","NT","1");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        mysql_select_db("test", $con);  

        if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && $_POST['firstName']) {
            $fName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
        }
        else 
            $fName = ""; // prevent from undefined var passed to mysql_query
        if(isset($_POST['lastName']) && $_POST['lastName']) {
            $lName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
        }
        else 
            $lName = ""; // prevent from undefined var passed to mysql_query
        if(isset($_POST['emailAddress']) && $_POST['emailAddress']) { 
                $emailAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailAddress']);
        }
        else 
            $emailAdd = ""; // prevent from undefined var passed to mysql_query
        if(isset($_POST['yearsExperience']) && $_POST['yearsExperience']) {
            $yExperience = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['yearsExperience']);
        }
        else 
            $yExperience = ""; // prevent from undefined var passed to mysql_query

        $query = "INSERT INTO NT.resume-storage (firstName, lastName, emailAddress, yearsExperience)
                VALUES ('$fName', '$lName', '$emailAdd', '$yExperience');";

        echo $query;

        if (mysql_query($query)) {
            echo "<h2>Thank you, your information has been stored in our Database.</h2>";
            mysql_close($con);
        }
        else{
            echo "<h2>Error</h2>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is a little bit dirty but can you tell me what it does ?

**EDITED**

Comment: Rather than modifying the code completely, first address the issue at hand. Please read my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344903/linking-a-resume-submission-html-form-to-submit-to-a-mysql-database#comment58397164_35344903). `$fName` and `$fname` are two different variable. Remove single quotes around table and column names. Also remove that `NULL, ` from the INSERT query.

Comment: John Smith, I tried your php code and it returns the following error:  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTSIResumeDB.php on line 15"                                 However, upon removal of the '}', it of course says theres an error with the else on the next line. thoughts?

Comment: I got the same line 16 "else" error, but im almost positive I placed the semicolons in the wrong places. can you specify which sections need one?

Comment: I can't run the script now. Did you copy paste my updated code ? You can try this with your code http://phpcodechecker.com

Comment: On the code checker site, it returns 6 uses of outdated mysql queries, nothing else.   But when I run it I return a text string that says:  "INSERT INTO resume-storage (firstName, lastName, emailAddress, yearsExperience) VALUES ('Kanye', 'West', 'kWest@gmail.com', '7');
Error"      Which shows me that it is fetching the values from the form, but not properly inserting them to the DB.  the resume-storage is the table inside DB named "test", but even when i replace it with test in the code it returns the same error-it just doesnt state a line number for the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: It must be a SQL error then. What does it say when you copy paste the generated query inside your mysql client ? And can you give me your table "resume-storage" definition ?

Comment: I tried it in both the PHP test site you suggested and pasted it into my php action file.  The action file is what I explained as returning that "Insert into..." string that returned 'Error' that I think is actually what the code was designed to return.        As for 'defining' my table, can you elaborate on what you mean by that?   And my apologies for late responses, I only work a couple of hours on 4 days of the week.

Comment: The generated query is the text "INSERT INTO blablabla..." before the "Error" message. You must have something to manage your database like phpMyAdmin, navicat or any other client (even the command line tools). I'd like to know what does the generated query produce as a result. Then the definition of a table is this table's description (columns, primary key, constraints, etc...). You can manage to get that with the query `DESCRIBE table;`

Comment: I am using PHPMyAdmin and when I go to the SQL tab and try the command "DESCRIBE table;" It simply returns the error that: "MySQL said: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table' at line 1"